# package naming inconsistency?

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

I'm a total newbie in Java so I'm likely doing something dumb but I created the following directory:

> / src / main / java / com / utransporter

And my first *java* file in that directory was `Itms.java` who's first line is:

```
 package com.utransporter;
```

I'm using the `vs-code` editor and it seemed pretty happy with that. In fact I can easily compile and package this file into a JAR. Hooray.

Now I thought ... why not create another class? So I created another file called `Response` who's first line is exactly the same package declaration. But to my shock and horror I find that vs-code is giving me the following:

[image: vs-code error msg]

Huh? I was sure this would work. What am I doing wrong? I thought **Maven** (which I'm using) was opinionated about putting the root of your source under "src / main / java" so I'd not have expected to see this in my package declaration and indeed do *not* see that in my first file. :(

---

file structure:

[image]

Comment: Jeez. Someone marked me down for this question? Why? I'm really struggling. Is there something wrong with the question?

Comment: Somehow vs-code thinks the source directory is `src`, not `src/main/java`. Fix the build path.

Comment: What folder is it in? And does VS Code have any idea about Maven? It looks like it's assuming your source root is just `src/`.

Comment: How do you fix the build path and why would it be different across two files in the same directory. As for vs-code knowing about Maven ... I can only say I think it does. It worked like a charm for my first file.

Comment: @chrylis the two files are both in `/src/main/java/com/utransporter` and both have the same package statement but only one of the two files has the above error.

Comment: If you run `mvn package` from the command line, can Maven build it successfully? If so, that would indicate that it's a problem with Visual Studio Code, not with Maven or with your code.

Comment: @DanielPryden yes good point ... it IS packaging so it would appear the limitation is with vs-code.